# HTML5 - forced to use elements for loose text in <body>?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html

I can't seem to find this in the HTML5 spec, but is it now necessary to have all text inside the `<body>` to be wrapped in some other element?  (ie. `<span>` `<div>`, etc)

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio's HTML5 parser so I'm trying to figure out if it's parsing bug or a legit spec change.

Comment: Paste you code to the validator and check http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid. The HTML5 spec for the [`body`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/sections.html#the-body-element-0) element states that the content allowed in it is "[flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/content-models.html#flow-content)". One of the things that makes up "flow content" is "[text](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/content-models.html#text-content)", and "text":

> Text, in the context of content models, means text nodes.

And a text node is just what you have.

The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) agrees, and passes your example as valid HTML5.

Comment: Thanks, I'll log the issue with the VS team.